# Jquery effect does only show quickly and does not stay

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a navigtion list. Each list element loads the same page. The selected list item shall become bolded. Without including the loading part, the 'making bold' part works proper. But with the loading part included, the list item only gets bolded for a second and then disappears.

Here is the code. Thanks very much for any hint.

```
$('.nav_main_body2 li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.nav_main_body2 li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.content_cnt').load('<?= base_url('home/subpages_subtabs'); ?>');
});
```

Comment: Please show the resulting HTML without PHP in it

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in below line because of incorrect string

```
$('.content_cnt').load('<?= base_url('home/subpages_subtabs'); ?>');
```

Try this

```
$('.nav_main_body2 li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.nav_main_body2 li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.content_cnt').load("<?= base_url('home/subpages_subtabs'); ?>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using codeigniter base_url() function to generate the URL?
If so you might want to use this:

```
$('.nav_main_body2 li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.nav_main_body2 li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.content_cnt').load("<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/subpages_subtabs");
});
```

Do not forget to load the [helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) first:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```